# How display data with FlatList from useQuery?

Tags: react-native, flatlist

Home Component :

```
export const Home: React.FC<Props> = (): any => {
  const [recipesList, setRecipesList] = useState([] as Array<any>);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_RECIPES);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getRecipes = () => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }

      if (loading) {
        return console.log("LOADING =>", loading)
      }

      setRecipesList(data);
    };

    getRecipes();
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Recipe recipesList={recipesList} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Recipe Component :

```
export const Recipe: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props): any => {
  const { recipesList } = props;

  const displayRecipe = ({ item }: any) => {
   console.log("RENDER ITEM")
   return null;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={recipesList}
        extraData={recipesList}
        numColumns={2}
        renderItem={displayRecipe}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Impossible to display data in the flatlist component, it never enters in the renderItem function no matter what I do. The recipesList is never empty when i log in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array to the Flatlists data prop.

Try to change this line:

```
setRecipesList(data);
```

To this:

```
// I'm guessing that your query is named getRecipes
setRecipesList(data.getRecipes);
```